# Rails: form's f.select not returning grand-belongs_to w/ default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, belongs-to

This part of the application has to do with the grading process for bids for a RFP.

Basically a Category (e.g.:  Cost, Company Profile, --and many others)
  has many TestCriteria.  (e.g.:  Price Comparison, Competitiveness of Daily Rate... )

A TestCriterium can have three GradingScores { fail, meet, and exceed } (with #s and descr)

Connecting it all together, a Grade is associated with a TestCriteria to which we assign a GradingScale.
I'd like to 'carry forward' the owning Category.

---

On entering a new Grade I have stored category_id, its 2nd grandparent so to speak.

In grade's _form on returning to EDIT,

> > I need a Category dropdown with the selected default being @grade.category_id
> >     There are two levels of this.
> >     The simple case as shown here, and then see below.

---

My most recent attempt included:

In grade's controller

```
  @categories = Category.where(:id => @grade.category_id)
```

and in _form

```
<% f.select :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@categories.sort_by
{ |cats| cats.category_name}, "id", "category_name",
:selected => @grade.category_id ) %>
```

I've also tried a simple Category.find() w/ parameters in _form.
If I can get help with this I can go a long ways in other matters.

**== NOW THE TRICKY VERSION ==**

This is all preliminary for what I REALLY NEED.

I'm using an jQuery ajax script to do the initial NEW entry of Category & TestCriterium & Grade.

Category limits the appropriate list of Tests,
and Test limits the apprpriate list of Grade options.

Here's the form for grades that I'm using to get this series of fields:

```
<div class="field">
<%= label_tag 'Evaluation Category' %><br/>
  <div id="grade_picker_div" >
        <%= collection_select( :category, :category_id, Category.find(:all, :order => "id"),
              :id, :category_name,{:include_blank => true} ) %><br/>
      <div id="tests_div"></div><br/>
      <div id="grades_div"></div><br/>
      </div>
</div>
```

And the ajax:

```
$ ->  
$('#grade_picker_div #category_category_id').change ->
#selected = $(this).attr 'value'
selected = $(':selected', this)[0].value
$.ajax '/categories/' + selected,
  type: 'get'
  dataType: 'json'
  error:  (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
     alert 'stop' + textStatus
  success:  (data, textStatus, errorThrown) -> 
    select_html = '<br><b>Test Criteria</b><br/> <select id="grade_test_criterium_id" name="grade[test_criterium_id]"><option></option>'
    for test_criterium in data.test_criteria
      select_html += '<option value="' + test_criterium.id + '">' + test_criterium.criteria + '</option>'  
    select_html += '</select>'
    $('#grade_picker_div #test_criteria_div').html(select_html)
    $('#grade_picker_div #grading_scales_div').html('')
return false 

$(document).on 'change', '#grade_picker_div #test_criteria_div', ->
selected = $(':selected', this)[0].value
#alert selected
$.ajax '/test_criteria/' + selected,
  type: 'get'
  dataType: 'json'
  error:  (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
    #alert 'stop' textStatus
  success:  (data, textStatus, errorThrown) -> 
    select_html = '<b>Grade</b><br/> <select id="grade_grading_scale_id" name="grade[grading_scale_id]"><option></option>'
    for grading_scale in data.grading_scales
      select_html += '<option value="' + grading_scale.id + '">' + grading_scale.name + " : " + grading_scale.description + '</option>'  
    select_html += '</select>'
    $('#grade_picker_div #grading_scales_div').html(select_html)
return false
```

I've done some cutting and pasting but the above code works.

> > After I learn how to do the simple preload of a dropdown, (the top part of this Q)
> >     how do you suggest I IF/THEN my way to make this work on the EDIT versus what works here for NEW?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you are using `select` so you should not use `options_from_collection_for_select` which creates an html string for a list of options. `select` does that for you.  try changing that to `collection_select`

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories.sort_by(&:category_name), :id, :category_name, { selected: @grade.category_id } %>
```

if `f.object` is equal to `@grade`, you don't need to pass the `selected` option.